# Replace missing values if fewer than x columns missing

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I would like to replace missing values in the columns `var1:var6` with zero for only those rows with fewer than 2 missing values in the `var1:var6` columns. I would then like to recalculate the sum column (I can happily use `rowwise()` as per my reprex for that).

I've tried a few things using `across()`, or `rowwise()` and `c_across()` but am struggling to find a solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate data
set.seed(40)
dat <- tibble(
  id = 1:6,
  var1 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
  var3 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
  var4 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
  var5 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
  var6 = sample(c(0:4, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(var1:var6))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This is the current tibble:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 6 × 8
     id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6   sum
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     4     4    NA    NA     2    NA
2     2    NA    NA     4     3     4     2    NA
3     3     4     4     1     1     4     1    15
4     4     1     2     4     4     4    NA    NA
5     5     2     1     4     4    NA     2    NA
6     6     1     3     1     0     0     4     9
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
> new_dat
# A tibble: 6 × 8
     id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6   sum
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     4     4    NA    NA     2    NA
2     2    NA    NA     4     3     4     2    NA
3     3     4     4     1     1     4     1    15
4     4     1     2     4     4     4     0    15
5     5     2     1     4     4     0     2    13
6     6     1     3     1     0     0     4     9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `across` like so:

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(var1:var6, ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x) & rowSums(is.na(across(var1:var6))) < 2, 0)),
         sum = rowSums(across(var1:var6)))

# # A tibble: 6 × 8
#      id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6   sum
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     4     4    NA    NA     2    NA
# 2     2    NA    NA     4     3     4     2    NA
# 3     3     4     4     1     1     4     1    15
# 4     4     1     2     4     4     4     0    15
# 5     5     2     1     4     4     0     2    13
# 6     6     1     3     1     0     0     4     9
```

Answer (score 3):

To minimally adjust your code with `rowwise()`, you can set the argument `na.rm` in `sum()` as a flexible logical value that indicates if that row has fewer than 2 missing value.

```r
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = c_across(var1:var6) %>% sum(na.rm = sum(is.na(.)) < 2)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 8
#      id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6   sum
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     3     4     4    NA    NA     2    NA
# 2     2    NA    NA     4     3     4     2    NA
# 3     3     4     4     1     1     4     1    15
# 4     4     1     2     4     4     4    NA    15
# 5     5     2     1     4     4    NA     2    13
# 6     6     1     3     1     0     0     4     9
```

Comment: Wow, did not know this `na.rm` trick! I will definitely add that to my routines

Comment: I think you need to convert NA to 0, on rows 4 and 5.

Comment: Great trick, and also worked. I accepted Maël's answer as it best fits the rest of my code. But your answer is very elegant!

Comment: I was really confused about what was playing the role of the first argument in `sum` here. From the docs for anyone else:  ...if the placeholder is only used in a nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument! The reason for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable code. For example, `iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` is equivalent to `iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` but slightly more compact.

Answer (score 2):

Base alternative, convert NAs to 0, if they appear at most once. Then get rowSums as usual:

```
cc <- grep("^var", colnames(dat), value = TRUE)
rr <- which(rowSums(is.na(dat[ cc ])) < 2)
dat[ rr, cc ][ is.na(dat[ rr, cc ]) ] <- 0

dat$sum <- rowSums(dat[ cc ])
#   id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 sum
# 1  1    3    4    4   NA   NA    2  NA
# 2  2   NA   NA    4    3    4    2  NA
# 3  3    4    4    1    1    4    1  15
# 4  4    1    2    4    4    4    0  15
# 5  5    2    1    4    4    0    2  13
# 6  6    1    3    1    0    0    4   9
```